# Método para eliminar un objeto de una archivo serializado en Java

Tags: java, serialización

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clases, donde puedo introducir, listar, buscar y eliminar uno o todos los objetos serializables que guardo en un archivo .dat. Me funcionan todos los métodos menos el de eliminar unos solo.
Cuando intento borrar un objeto no me lo borra y me vuelve a mostrar el listado original con todos los objetos.
Me podrían ayudar?

```
public static void borrarCliente(String borrarNif){
    File ficheroEntrada=null;
    File ficheroSalida=null;
    FileInputStream flujoEntrada=null;
    FileOutputStream flujoSalida=null;
    ObjectInputStream lector=null;
    ObjectOutputStream escritor=null;
    try{
        ficheroEntrada =new File("clientes.dat");
        ficheroSalida = new File("temporal.dat");
        flujoEntrada = new FileInputStream(ficheroEntrada);
        flujoSalida = new FileOutputStream (ficheroSalida);
        lector = new ObjectInputStream (flujoEntrada);
        escritor = new ObjectOutputStream(flujoSalida);
        boolean finalFichero=false;
        Clientes cliente = null;
        cliente=(Clientes)lector.readObject();
        while(lector.available()>0){ // mientras no lleguemos al final del fichero

            if(!borrarNif.equals(cliente.dni)){
                escritor.writeObject(cliente);
            }

        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado");
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("Error de fichero");
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    try{

        escritor.close();
        lector.close();
        ficheroEntrada.delete();
        ficheroSalida.renameTo(ficheroEntrada);
        ficheroSalida.delete(); // Borramos el fichero temporal
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("Error de fichero");
    }
}
```

Comment: Solo estás leyendo un registro. Esta instrucción: `cliente=(Clientes)lector.readObject();` debe agregarse adentro del bucle while.

Comment: Hola, Lo he cambiado dentro del while como me has dicho pero sigue sin funcionar. Lo que pretendo es que vuelva a crear el archivo clientes.dat sin el registro que quiero borrar pero cuando vuelvo a listarlo me salen todos. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica en esta sentencia:

```java
while(lector.available()>0)
```

El método `available` esta retornando un `0` y por eso la condición nunca se cumpla.

El método `readObject` lanza la excepción [EOFException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) cuando llega al final del archivo, es decir, cuando ya no hay más datos que leer y esto nos puede servir para lograr romper el bucle `while`.

También se debe tomar en cuenta que el método `readObject` hay que invocarlo adentro del bucle `while`, de lo contrario, solo estarías deserializando un objeto y se supone deben ser más de uno.

Así quedaría el código:

```java
try
{
    ficheroEntrada =new File("clientes.dat");
    ficheroSalida = new File("temporal.dat");
    flujoEntrada = new FileInputStream(ficheroEntrada);
    flujoSalida = new FileOutputStream (ficheroSalida);
    lector = new ObjectInputStream (flujoEntrada);
    escritor = new ObjectOutputStream(flujoSalida); 
    Clientes cliente;
    //El bucle se rompe cuando el método readObject lance EOFException 
    while(true)
    { 
        cliente = (Clientes)lector.readObject();
        if(!borrarNif.equals(cliente.dni))
        {
            escritor.writeObject(cliente);
        }   
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
{
    System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado");
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{
    //ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Como la clase `IOException` es la clase padre de `EOFException`, se puede atrapar la excepción con dicha clase.

Eliminé la variable `finalArchivo` porque en ningún momento la usabas y tampoco es necesario inicializar la variable `cliente` ya que solo la estás utilizando adentro del bucle `while`.

**Recomendaciones:**

**1-.** El nombre de la clase `Clientes` no debería estar en plural, sino, en singular y esto se debe porque la clase solo es para un cliente. Si se hubiese llamado `ListaClientes`, ahí fuera diferente, porque esto quiere decir que la clase servirá para almacenar más de un cliente.

**2-.** No es necesario esta instrucción:

```java
ficheroSalida.delete(); // Borramos el fichero temporal
```

Así que la puedes eliminar y esto se debe porque al cambiar el nombre del fichero temporal, ya no necesitas eliminar nada y esto lo compruebas verificando el valor que devuelva el método `delete` (que obviamente retorna `false` porque hubo una falla al eliminar).

**3-.** No deberías liberar los recursos directamente en el bloque `try`:

```java
try{
    escritor.close();
    lector.close();
```

Si el primer método `close()` arrojara una excepción, lo que esté debajo de dicha instrucción, no se ejecutará, por lo tanto, ocurrirá [fuga de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria).

Así que debes usar dos bloques `try-catch` de forma separada:

```java
try
{
    escritor.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

try 
{
    lector.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

ficheroEntrada.delete();
ficheroSalida.renameTo(ficheroEntrada);
```

Para no tener que estar escribiendo todo ese código puedes usar el bloque [ARM](https://www.infoq.com/news/2010/08/arm-blocks/) que se añadió a partir de Java 7 y de esta forma, no necesitas liberar los recursos manualmente, ya que todo se hace de manera automática.

El código quedaría así con bloque ARM:

```java
ficheroEntrada =new File("clientes.dat");
ficheroSalida = new File("temporal.dat");
try(FileInputStream flujoEntrada = new FileInputStream(ficheroEntrada);
    FileOutputStream flujoSalida = new FileOutputStream (ficheroSalida))
{
    lector = new ObjectInputStream (flujoEntrada);
    escritor = new ObjectOutputStream(flujoSalida); 
    Cliente cliente;
    while(true)
    { 
        cliente = (Cliente)lector.readObject();
        if(!borrarNif.equals(cliente.dni))
        {
            escritor.writeObject(cliente);
        }   
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
{
    System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado");
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{
    //ioe.printStackTrace();
}
ficheroEntrada.delete();
ficheroSalida.renameTo(ficheroEntrada);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y recomendaciones. Ahora me he dado cuenta que tengo algo mal al añadir nuevos clientes porque cuando los añado es cuando no me funciona lo de borrar clientes que me has recomendado.
Sin embargo, si entro en la aplicación sin añadir ningún registro nuevo si me funciona lo de borrar un cliente. Deja de funcionar al añadir uno nuevo.